# I want to extends enum and object (generic)

Tags: java, generics, object, enums, classcastexception

`Enum` is in the `java.lang.Enum`, and `Object` is in the `java.lang.Object`. So, why is `Enum` not an `Object`? (I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException`)

I want to make a class that can accept both `Object` and `Enum`, like this...

```
public class MyType<T extends Enum<T>, Object> {
```

But this gives a compilation error. How can i make my `MyType` so that it can accept all (or both) type of classes? (`Enum` or `Object`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Enum is an Object. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html
So

```
MyType<Object> {
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. my first problem is solved. but, i cant cast T[] to enum[] type. ex, enum ITEM{}; myType = new MyType<ITEM>(); ITEM[] items = myType.getData(); // getData() return T[]. why cant cast? in console : java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljtrix.manager.ItemManager$ITEM;

Comment: Glad I could help. You might want to upvote and/or accept :-) Edit: I see your additions now: since that is a different question, I would post it in a different thread!

Comment: Arrays types are covariant, which means that `Object[]` is a *superclass* of any `MyType[]`. In other words, `MyType[] instanceof Object[]` is `true` and the reverse is, obviously, `false`. There is no way you can cast an `Object[]` into any other array type. Also take note that the type of array is its runtime property, not compile-time like generics.

Answer (score 2):

Since every Java object is `instanceof Object`, there is nothing better to do than declare `MyType<?>` with no bounds. That will capture any type, including an enum type.

Answer (score 0):

You can see on [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and
>   only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any
>   other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of
>   Object.

You can conclude:

1. even not explicit your class will extends from `Object`;
2. if `Object` was a figured manner to represent other class, you will not be able since java doesn't support multiple-inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by looking at the API for class object, you can read:

```
Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. 
All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.
```

This means that `Enum` is an object (you can verify this by looking at the JavaDocs for [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) aswell). Hence, if you simply tell `MyType` to contain Object(`MyType<Object>`), it will accept Object and Enum as you originally posted.

Although notice that this might cause unwanted behavior and is considered unsafe, since ALL classes are objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've stated your question correctly. I think you want your class to accept `Enum` *or* `Object`. When you put it like that you can see that  is the only possible choice.

If you want it to accept `Enum` *and* `Object`, that is equivalent to saying 'accept `Enum`'. In which case > is the answer.